# AppleScript to change resolutions on my monitor

Tags: applescript, screen, resolution

I have reviewed multiple scripts that address primarily changes on a retina display.  I have a standard monitor (iMac 27").  The line of code that seems to give me trouble is:

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "iMac"

I have substituted the name of the window containing the parameters of my monitor (see picture).

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks.[image]

Comment: What is giving you trouble with that line? Do you get an error message? I don't seem to have any problem with that line running it myself. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on how to create a reproducible problem with a code snippet.

Comment: I finally found a script to identify elements of that window.  The trouble I am having is with the last function:  the choice of the exact resolution I need.  I am using:  click row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window "iMac"  I get an error.  Maybe "click" is the the correct operator?

Comment: Edit your question with the script, don't post it as a comment. Narrow it down to the shortest possible script to reproduce the problem.

Comment: tell application "System Preferences"
 reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
 click radio button "Display" of tab group 1 of window "iMac"
 click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1 of tab group 1 of window "iMac"
 click row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window "iMac"
end tell                      this script returns "missing value"  but the UI that I got clearly says row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1

Comment: Comments are ephemeral and don’t support proper formatting, **[edit] your question** with the script formatted correctly. This also puts your question into the reopen queue for people to see your question.